# How can I generate valid jwt tokens?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt

For my api I'm trying to generate a jwt token in order to controll access to my api with the use of [Authorize].

I cant seem to figure out why its not generating correct ones, here is my generating code:

```
public string GetToken(User user)
{
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:Key"]);
    
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Audience = _configuration["JWT:Audience"],
        Issuer = _configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim("id", user.Id) }),
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };
    
    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    
    return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
}
```

This produces the token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6InVzZXItODU5MTdkNzctMzQ2OC00OTNmLWIyNjYtM2YwYTdjMmVkZmIzIiwibmJmIjoxNjQ4NjcxMzEwLCJleHAiOjE2NDkyNzYxMTAsImlhdCI6MTY0ODY3MTMxMCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdCIsImF1ZCI6IndlYmFwaXVzZXJzIn0.sgpBNGHPcfG0tuecbt8kKh99HoeiY2lYJJ-jCiEBypo:832DKHCVFDYAY0BD
```

And If I paste it into jwt.io it states that its signature is invalud. Futher more, if I use it on autorized actions i get "Unauthorized".

Im my setup of the API i've set up the authoriaztion like this:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    var Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("JWT:Key"));

    o.SaveToken = true;
    
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("JWT:Issuer"),
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("JWT:Audience"),
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Key)
    };
});
```

It should validate more, but for the time being Ill use a minimal setup. And I of course have the using

```
...
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Any idea why I get unauthorized on my requests?

Comment: When you checked it on jwt.io, did you also input your secret?

Comment: @Crowcoder Yepp, then I get "signature verified". Do I have to do something more? Add the secret on the client side and append the token? For with the token i get Unauthorized